# searching with a name in database for a person - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my table I store first name in the `fName` column and last name in the `lName` column, now I need to search them with a query, but I don't know the SQL!

example

```
   lName | fName  
-----------------
Tendulkar| Sachin   
Ganguly  | Sourav   
Khan     | Zaheer  
Dhoni    | Mahendra Singh
```

The user should get MAHENDRA SINGH DHONI if he searches for Mahendra Dhoni!

Comment: Define searching for "mahendra dhoni"?  Does that mean you know the last name specifically?  Does it mean that you only know the complete string by the user?  Does it mean you have both the first and last name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select concat(fName,' ',lName) fullname
from tbl
where concat(' ',fName,' ',lName,' ') like '% Mahendra %'
  and concat(' ',fName,' ',lName,' ') like '% dhoni %'
```

This will most certainly put to rest any hopes of a well performing query

A variation on the theme

```
select concat(fName,' ',lName) fullname
from tbl
where (concat(fName,' ',lName) like '%Mahendra%dhoni%'
    or concat(lName,' ',fName) like '%Mahendra%dhoni%')
```

The 2nd version doesn't care about full part matching, e.g. dhoni will match madhonie

---

Both of these queries find the name correctly.  Note that there are % before and after the name to match, as well as % for every space in the name.

```
create table tbl (fname varchar(100), lname varchar(100));
insert tbl select 'Mahendra singh', 'dhoni';

select concat(fName,' ',lName) fullname
from tbl
where (concat(fName,' ',lName) like '%Mahendra%dhoni%'
    or concat(lName,' ',fName) like '%Mahendra%dhoni%');

select concat(fName,' ',lName) fullname
from tbl
where (concat(fName,' ',lName) like '%dhoni%Mahendra%'
    or concat(lName,' ',fName) like '%dhoni%Mahendra%');
```

Comment: your query works if i search for Mahendra Dhoni but fails if i search for Dhoni Mahendra, i need to built a person search feature like Facebook, orkut, where user can search with Last Name First Name or First Name Last Name, i think you can help !

Comment: i dont know, but it worked for the Mahendra Dhoni perfectly but not for Dhoni Mahendra [returns empty result set]

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi nope sir, the same problem happens :(

Comment: i need to write a SQL which return the same result for BILL GATES and GATES BILL [just like Facebook orkut do]

Comment: @Sourav / I double-checked and tested it

Comment: This assumes way too much about the strings the person asking the question has.  I would never suggest the usage of concat, or and like all in the same query as that would produce the worst possible explain ever and he just might use the technique on a large database and kill without understanding why.

Comment: your query worked, but i'm unable to vote up, coz when i press the up arrow it shows -1 !

Answer (score 1):

You are not clear on the nature of the search inputs and specifically the level of flexibility. First, is the user given two boxes for first and last name or only a single search box? If the former, then the fast solution would be:

```
Select concat( fname, ' ', lname)
From MyTable
Where lname Like 'dhoni%'
    And fname Like 'mahendra%'
```

The above query only searches for where the first part of the column value begins with the search values. However, if the user can type anything into a single search box, that is harder. If it is presumed that the user has typed `<name part> space <name part>`, then one solution that solves that specific problem where the user enters only two words is to split on the space and run something like:

```
Select concat( fname, ' ', lname)
From MyTable
Where ( lname Like '%dhoni%' And fname Like '%mahendra%' )
    Or ( lname Like '%mahendra%' And fname Like '%dhoni%' )
```

However, that query will perform awful because it forces the system to scan the entire table each time it is executed. Further, what happens when they enter a three part name like `Mahendra Singh Dhoni` in your search? There are simply too many edge cases for this to be workable IMO. The right solution is to get a full text indexing engine like Lucene that will create a index across both columns and rank the quality of the match.

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)

Comment: your 2nd query worked, and you are write that for 3  or more words the sql gets broken :( i am building a facebook orkut like search feature with PHP / MySQL, can you help me on it ?

Comment: @Sourav - The solution is a search engine. Keep in mind you are assuming a space as a word delimiter. There could be hyphens, apostrophes and so on. Also it should be noted that a search on the reverse of the names probably isn't always going to be correct. You may get a situation where "Smyth Bob" exists a person separate from "Bob Smyth". A search engine that provides ranking is right solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your inputs are from two different textboxes, and hopefully you are using a stored procedure :).

```
declare @input1 nvarchar(50)
declare @input2 nvarchar(5)
set @input1 = 'Mahendra'
set @input2 = 'Dhoni'

select upper((fname + ' ' + lname)) as 'FullName' 
from customer
where fname like '%' + @input1 + '%'
or fname like '%' + @input1 + '%'
or lname like '%' + @input2 + '%'
or lname like '%' + @input2 + '%'
```

If you have 1 input box, you will want to split your search term by the space and loop over your search terms against fname and lname columns using the like '%term%' syntax.

Another way would be to make a stored procedure that added fname and lname together and did a soundex match. this is where you match your search term against the sound of the word in the table. Google it should help, its pretty easy.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you have 2 inputs and you are only getting part of the first name.  If this is true then the following would work:

```
select concat(fname, ' ', lname)
  from yourtable
 where substring(fname, 1, 5) = 'mahen'
   and lname = 'dhoni'
```

The advantage of this approach is that it will use the indexes on the column(s) or a combined index whereas the `like` queries always do full table scans.

You might also check out a search engine like sphinx or solr when you truly do not know the data you are receiving as those are far more flexible that database queries.

Comment: If you read the comments under my answer, you will see that OP wants exactly what he wants - not some cut down sub-string "starts with" search, and certainly not having to decide between last/first name (search should do both ways). Let me know when you can better my query given the same constraints.

Comment: I don't know about Facebook, but if you searched "ary" in Orkut, you get matches like "D!NE$# C#aud#ary".

Comment: @Richard First off I clearly explained the parameters of my solution which is perfectly fine but thank for the vote down anyway.  The real solution is a search engine like I said if you have a string across multiple columns in the db.  What was your point about Orkut and how is that different than what your query would produce if the data was in the db btw?

Comment: @greg give me a technical reason as to why it is a bad answer?

Comment: @wes / If you take the approach of redefining requirements until you can answer it trivially... then you have an interesting approach. My point about Orkut (I thought I was clear) is that it performs a contains search on *any* of first and last name, not just the beginning of *either one only*. Not only that, but SUBSTRING will not use an index, but LIKE 'mahen%' will